# Is it necessary to protect GRUB with a password if your volumes are encrypted with LUKS?

Tags: linux, security, encryption, grub, luks

I understand there are vulnerabilities around somebody using grub to boot into single user mode and escalate privilages on your machine.

But is there any purpose in doing this if your volume is fully encrypted? In other words, if you have a strong password protecting all of your data, can an attacker actually *do* anything from single user mode, if they still can't decrypt your data?

Comment: If an attacker has physical access to a device than all bets are off. It just depends on what your data is worth and how long someone is prepared to try and steal it.

Comment: Then grub password is easy to remove by  people with access to the disk. Encryption is useful if the kernel cannot be altered (UEFI boot).

Comment: Doesn't that make the grub password meaningless? Generally, when you're in grub, you don't have network yet. So the only case where you would have access to grub, but not the disk that I can think of is either network boot, or a rack of VMs, right?